# Can I setup Chaplin without routes?

Tags: backbone.js, routes, chaplinjs

As we plan to use Chaplin for Mobile and want to keep it lightweight, is it possible we use Chaplin without routes, but activate the controller manually (we will use a single controller only, but possibly multiple views) ?

Can this be done by just using the dispatcher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers expect routes as parameters in a number of their methods. Similarly, the dispatcher is tightly coupled with routes management, and it does all the controller loading, callbacks and execution.

If you want to do away with routes, you'll have to rewrite the dispatcher to get rid of routes, and modify the `new` method of the controllers to disregard routes.

Alternatively, set up only a single route and it'll do exactly what you want. Why do you want to get rid of routes? One route, one controller. The dispatcher works fine in that case, and has very little overhead because the controller behavior is cached when the route doesn't change.